Why does autofilter run slowly after running VBA code?
I have a very strange problem.  I have a large Excel data set (100k+ rows) with an autofilter.  The autofilter runs fine on the main sheet, but after running some code (does multiple calculations and then hard codes the values) the autofilter then runs very slow. Every time I change or clear a filter (previously took 1 second, now takes 10+ seconds).
The only change is the values in the table from running the code.  I've done all the standard stuff:

All the values are hard coded (i.e. no formulas in the data) and
there are no formulas referencing the data.

There are no excess lines at the end of the data.

I have all the standard code at the start and end of the VBA code (see below).

I tried saving the file to see if there was some temp cache data that would clear when saving.

There is no conditional formatting or any other formatting in the table.
Additional context (Office 365, and the file is on One Drive, autosave is turned off).  If anyone has any ideas it will be greatly appreciated.
 Sub ValueChange()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.EnableEvents = False


 'Sample of Code
With ws2.Range("V34:Y" & RowCount)
         .Formula = "=Round(Staging!A34-IFERROR((1/Main!$Z34-1/Main!$FD34),0),2)"  'write formula to all cells
         .value = .value           'replace formula by values
         End With

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True


 End Sub




does your workbook include code that reacts to an event (e.g. worksheet change event)?

Hi. There are no worksheet change events. I just double checked to make sure.

Is your data range formatted as a ListObject/Table?

No it is not.  I'll play around with that to assess the impact.  Thank you.

I narrowed it down to: when automatic update formulas (Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic) turns on within the VBA code it seems to slow down the autofilter (even when it is switched to manual calculation again the autofilter continues to run slow).   Very strange as there are no formulas or formatting in the entire workbook and resetting the formulas calculation back to xlManual does not return it to the previous speed.
